# How to display multiple dropdown list using javscript with if else statement?

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement

**Hi Friends,
I am in the beginning stage in javascript, Trying to create a small web application in javascript but, unable to print the drop-down list output
Please help me to fix the issue**

```
<html>
  <body>
    <p>SELECT THE STATE:
      <select id="select2"> 
        <option value="regiona">TAMILNADU</option>
        <option value="regionb">ANDHRA PRADESH</option>
      </select>
    </p>
    <span class="output1"></span>
    <p>SELECT THE ROUTER TYPE: 
      <select id="select1"> 
        <option value="accessa">ASR9K</option>
        <option value="accessa">ASR920</option>
      </select>
    </p> 
    <span class="output"></span>
    <button onclick="apply()">APPLY</button> 
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
      function apply() { 
        selectElement = document.querySelector('#select1','#select2'); 
        var output = selectElement.value;
        var output1 = selectElement.value;  
        document.querySelector('.output','.output1').textContent = output,output1;
        if (output === 'accessa' || output1 === 'regiona' ) {
          document.write('<h1 style ="color: #ff0000;">TAMILNADU</h1>');
        }
        else if (output === 'accessa' || output1 === 'regionb' ) {
          document.write('<h1 style ="color: #ff0000;">ANDHRA PRADESH</h1>');
        }
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your best bet when needing to show a particular element based on logic, then include all three of your select lists, but initially hide them (style="display:none;") and then perform what ever logic you need to determine which select list you want to show and make it visible by setting it's style.display="inline-block" in javascript.  You can use the document.querySelector( ... ) to individually access the select list.

Comment: Are you aware that both `option value`s of `select id="select1"` are `"accessa"`?
Did you want the second one to be `"accessb"`?

Comment: I understand you're just learning, but `document.write` is a _terrible_ way to put things on the page in modern javascript. That's really a problem with old tutorials living forever. I also have to disagree with Howard Brown's comment above. While the gist of his "best bet" is the right direction, it is better to manipulate _classes_ on the elements, rather than manipulating `style.display` directly — and whether you use `display:inline-block` or `display:block` (or even something else) depends on the rest of the structure of your page.

Comment: @iAmOren     I have created an application using python code that's works well(python with tkiniter)

It should be used on webserver so, i'm trying to use javascript (HTML+CSS+JAVASCRIPT+PYTHON_FLASK FRAMEWORK)


**accessb** _is required for the code to be developed from now on

If i get the output to see **accessa** in the code above, i will take care of the rest code_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This uses your `<span class="output">` to display the chosen values rather than using `document.write` to create new `<h1>` elements. This could do the same thing using an h1 instead of a span, and the location in the page can be anything you want — I just left the spans where you originally put them.

There are many differences between what I wrote and your original page and code.

I've changed the HTML to use more logical and descriptive names for classes and IDs, which makes the code more understandable. For example, rather than generic names like "output" and "output2" I use "state-output" and "router-output".

I get the elements that are involved in the function just once, when the page loads, rather than when the function is called. Those elements never change, so getting the elements every time the function is called is unnecessary overhead. In this brief case it doesn't matter much, because the function is probably only going to be called once.

I'm using some cascading ternary operators (`? :`) because it's briefer than a series of if-else statements. This could also be done with a switch statement, or by using a map of values to words

```
{
    'regiona' : 'TAMILNADU',
    'regionb' : 'ANDHRA PRADESH'
}
```

I style everything separately using CSS, rather than having duplicate inline `style="..."` that would need to be kept consistent by changing them *everywhere* they appear.

```js
document.getElementById('apply-button').addEventListener('click', apply);

const stateElement  = document.getElementById('state-select');
const stateOutput   = document.getElementById('state-output');
const routerElement = document.getElementById('router-select');
const routerOutput  = document.getElementById('router-output');

function apply() {
    const stateVal = stateElement.value;
    const routerVal = routerElement.value;

    stateOutput.innerText =
        stateVal === 'regiona' ? 'TAMILNADU' :
        stateVal === 'regionb' ? 'ANDHRA PRADESH' :
        'unknown';

    routerOutput.innerText = routerVal;
}
```

```css
section {
    margin: 0 0 1em 0;
}
span.output {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 2em;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: darkgreen;
}
```

```html
<section class="selections">
    <p>SELECT THE STATE:</p>
    <select id="state-select"> 
        <option value="regiona">TAMILNADU</option>
        <option value="regionb">ANDHRA PRADESH</option>
    </select>
    <span id="state-output" class="output"></span>

    <p>SELECT THE ROUTER TYPE:</p>
    <select id="router-select"> 
        <option value="ASR9K">ASR9K</option>
        <option value="ASR920">ASR920</option>
    </select>
    <span id="router-output" class="output"></span>
</section>

<section class="button-set">
    <button type="button" id="apply-button">Apply</button> 
</section>
```

In place of my use of the ternary operator you could use some if-else logic or a switch statement

```
stateOutput.innerText =
    stateVal === 'regiona' ? 'TAMILNADU' :
    stateVal === 'regionb' ? 'ANDHRA PRADESH' :
    'unknown';
```

would become this if-else

```
if (stateVal === 'regiona') {
    stateOutput.innerText = 'TAMILNADU';
}
else if (stateVal === 'regionb') {
    stateOutput.innerText = 'ANDHRA PRADESH';
}
else {
    stateOutput.innerText = 'unknown';
}
```

or this switch-case

```
switch (stateVal) {
    case 'regiona':
        stateOutput.innerText = 'TAMILNADU';
        break;
    case 'regionb':
        stateOutput.innerText = 'ANDHRA PRADESH';
        break;
    default:
        stateOutput.innerText = 'unknown';
        break;
}
```

Comment: **Thank you very much .. The given code works well.

Could you tell me how to use this code with the _if else, else if_ statement?**

Comment: @pragalathmsp I added how you would use an if-else and a switch-case

Answer (score 0):

```
function apply() {
  output1 = document.querySelector('#select1').value;
  output2 = document.querySelector('#select2').value;
  document.querySelector('.output').textContent = output1;
  document.querySelector('.output1').textContent = output2;


  if (output === 'accessa' || output1 === 'regiona') {
    document.write('<h1 style ="color: #ff0000;">TAMILNADU</h1>');
  } else if (output === 'accessa' || output1 === 'regionb') {
    document.write('<h1 style ="color: #ff0000;">ANDHRA PRADESH</h1>');
  }
}
```

there are multiple reasons your code doesn't work,

1. you can't select multiple elements with `querySelector`
2. while setting the text values you were not assigning to both variables

UPDATE:

you have a duplicate value for the select1 value `accessa` twice. so updated that and also on the `else if` conditional you are checking `output =='accessa'` again on top of checking it inside the `if` just before.

so i have updated the whole script

```
<option value="accessb">ASR920</option>
...
function apply() {
 var select1 = document.getElementById("select1");
 var select2 = document.getElementById("select2");
 output1 = select1.options[select1.selectedIndex].value;
 output2 = select2.options[select2.selectedIndex].value;
 if (output1 === 'accessa' || output2 === 'regiona') {
   document.write('<h1 style ="color: #ff0000;">TAMILNADU</h1>');
 } else if (output1 === 'accessb' || output2 === 'regionb') {
   document.write('<h1 style ="color: #ff0000;">ANDHRA PRADESH</h1>');
 }
}
```

Comment: **Thanks for your info but I have to print TAMILNADU or ANDHRA PRADESH when I click the button based on the selected droplist

I tried the given code, but it prints the option value (regiona,regionb and accessa)**